# Do I get MMR when the ranked game ended as a win while I'm disconnected?

Tags: dota-2

I'm new to Dota 2, and my connection isn't stable.

Do I get MMR when the ranked game ended as a win while I'm **disconnected while the game was ending**? *For instance, the game ended 3 minutes after I get disconnected. That means, I missed the ending. But my team won.*

Do I get MMR from this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Depends when you abandon. If it's an early abandonment (less than 5 minutes elapsed) then it's not counted, But if it's more than that then it gets counted.

Either way you'll be placed in low priority for a couple of games should this happen.

[Source](https://dota2.fandom.com/wiki/Stats#Abandonment)

Comment: Is this true even if you haven't been disconnected for long enough to have received an abandon yet when the game ends?

Comment: @ShrimpFan I didn't get what you mean as you mentioned "abandon" when I asked about "disconnect". Also, what do you mean by "early" disconnection is not counted (for MMR rewarding). I was asking about the moment of game ending while I was disconnected.